# Create a list from an array

Tags: google-sheets

I am using google sheets and trying to create a list from 2 ranges. One range is lot numbers and the other range is account balance. If there is a number greater than zero in the account balance range I need it to return the number in the corresponding lot range.

I am using the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(A4:A13, MATCH(0, COUNTIFS(B4:B13>0, A4:A13), 0)))
```

This is easy to accomplish with the formula provided by Chris. Remember to keep the cells below the filter formula empty. Any data in the cells below the formula will throw an error. I updated the attachment spreadsheet with the proper formula entered on D18.

My result is a list of all lot numbers instead of a list of lots with an account balance.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kt4rPECAVVHhZOXeA3FHGriXIfAg6H5BqRu-vTA_Pnk/edit?usp=sharing

The link includes a sample of my spreadsheet with my result and below is a sample of my expected result for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula in cell D13:

`=FILTER(A18:A27,B18:B27>0)`

Comment: Thank you. I apparently took the long way around and this is much simpler.